# Docker Swarm overlay network - containers can’t communicate

Tags: linux, windows, docker, networking, docker-swarm

Tl;dr: Docker swarm containers using overlay network can’t ping eachother

I am trying to create a swarm, which includes my Desktop (Windows with Docker Desktop) and a Ubuntu VM (Swarm manager, on my Desktop PC).

Creating the swarm and joining it works fine. I proceded to create an attachable overlay network, which should span all my nodes using the overlay driver. I have created a random nginx service, using global mode and my overlay network to make the network available on all my nodes.

To test the connectivity I created two ubuntu containers (One on Ubuntu, one on my Windows) and joined them to the network. The Problem is that the containers can’t ping eachother.I have also opened the required ports for swarm (2376, 2377, 7946, 4789) on my Windows and Ubuntu VM.

Docker version for Linux:

`Version: 19.03.6 
 API version: 1.40 
 Go version: go1.12.16`

Docker version for Windows:

`Version: 19.03.5 
 API version: 1.40 
 Go version: go1.12.12`

Do you know how I can make the connection work?

Comment: List your docker compose.

Comment: I am not using docker compose atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your question as I am in a similar scenario.

The documentation states that overlay networks are encrypted by default and that you shouldn't attempt to attach Windows nodes to an encrypted network:

> Do not attach Windows nodes to encrypted overlay networks.
>
> Overlay network encryption is not supported on Windows. If a Windows node attempts to connect to an encrypted overlay network, no error is detected but the node cannot communicate.

https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#encrypt-traffic-on-an-overlay-network

Comment: Great answer, I dont know how I could miss this in the docs...
Do you know of a way to deactivate the encryption so windows nodes work too?

Comment: @derteufelqwe did you find a work-around ? I'm having the very same problem.

Comment: @wworrall did u find a solution

Comment: @DennisJansky Yes, stop using docker for windows 10. Docker desktop / docker desktop with wsl backend and docker desktop directly installed in wsl doesn't work. I poured weeks into finding a solution and I it's just not possible atm.
Use linux only and everything works fine.